# Why isn't the boolean in my dictionary working?

Tags: python

This is clearly not working properly.

Why is this happening?

```
>>> d = {0 : "a", 1 : "b", 2 : "c", 3 : "d", True: 99}
>>> print d
{0: 'a', 1: 99, 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}
>>>
```

Comment: Because `True == 1` is true.

Comment: This is a duplicate, an often-encountered trap. You can't put in `False` either, because `False == 0`.

Comment: Or rather, whichever type is added as a key first, wins; `{True: 'boolean', 1: 'integer'}` will leave you with `{True: 'integer'}`..

Comment: @DeveloperXY - Uh.. it prints `True`. Did you mean `print int(True)`?

Comment: @BingsF In deed, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 1):

`True == 1`. There are reasons to disagree with that design decision, but that's how things are in Python. (Similarly, `False == 0`.) You can't have two equal keys in a dict, so you can't have both `True` and `1` as keys in the same dict.